# ASP.NET DataTable output problem

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable, viewstate

I can't for the life of me work out what I am doing wrong here, despite much searching on SO/Google.

Basically I have a simple DataTable which is held in ViewState and adjusted during postbacks. When I try to write out the values, it is just an empty string. Please find below an abbreviated example of what I have - the output in this case just winds up as a string of apostrophes (one for each execution) so it looks as though the rows are being added, but the ("Product") column is empty.

Thanks for your help.

```
    Dim dtItems As New DataTable
    If ViewState("Items") Is Nothing Then
        Dim dcColumn As DataColumn
        dcColumn = New DataColumn()
        dcColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String")
        dcColumn.ColumnName = "Product"
        dtItems.Columns.Add(dcColumn)
        ViewState("Items") = dtItems
    End If
    dtItems = CType(ViewState("Items"), DataTable)
    Dim drRow As DataRow
    drRow = dtItems.NewRow()
    drRow("Product") = "The Product"
    dtItems.Rows.Add()
    For Each drRow In dtItems.Rows
        txtTestDT.Text += drRow(("Product")).ToString & "!"
    Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replacing:

```
dtItems.Rows.Add()
```

with

```
dtItems.Rows.Add(drRow)
```

Comment: :) No worries...we all have moments like that!